# Customizing google ColumnChart in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I was trying to customize google Column chart to add my own data from controller. 
I found easy solution but if someone knows better approach I am happy to modify my code.

Assuming that we copy the code from https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
              ['2004',  1000,      400],
              ['2005',  1170,      460],
              ['2006',  660,       1120],
              ['2007',  1030,      540]
            ]);

            var options = {
              title: 'Company Performance',
              hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        </script>

    <div id="chart_div" style="width:50%;float:left"></div>
```

So the first think I wanted to amend was to display Category name and number of orders. 
Solution was simple, I just removed Expensed so it looked like this:

```
['Category', 'Orders'],
  ['2004',  1000,],
  ['2005',  1170, ],
  ['2006',  660,  ],
  ['2007',  1030, ]
```

But those are hard coded data and I wanted to have my own category names and name of orders from my Data base.

I created in controller custom string and then pass it to script.

Controller:

```
foreach (var d in model.DinerCategoryOrders) // Build  string for google chart js
        { 
          // ['Pre-School', 1000], Template

            GoogleOrdersCount += "['" + d.CategoryName + "', " +  d.OrdersCount + "],";  
        }
        model.OrdersForGoogleChart = "google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Category', 'Orders']," + GoogleOrdersCount +" ]);";

 return model;
```

In View

I replaced data variable definition simply with my string that I built in controller:

@Html.Raw(Model.OrdersForGoogleChart)

so final build looks like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = @Html.Raw(Model.OrdersForGoogleChart)

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

I found amazing that Razor in Asp.Net MVC speaks with js and js will digest string that was passed through razor without any issues.

If you find a beter solution to I believe common problem let us know!

Comment: I did mine a bit differently but this helped me, thanks.